# Как получить индекс элемента в listwidget по нажатию кнопки в нём. Pyside6

Tags: python, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton, pyside6, qlistwidget

Мне требуется получить индекс элемента в `listwidget` при нажатии кнопки в нём.

**Ожидание:** я нажимаю кнопку (не элемент) в **`item 5`** и  получаю ответ что это **`5  item`**.

**Реальность:** Я получаю только индекс последнего элемента (19) скорее всего это потому что i уже прошел цикл.

Как можно подключить кнопку так, чтобы она всегда выдавала индекс элемента?

Минимально воспроизводимый пример: (сделан лишь как пример, могут быть ошибки)

```
import sys

from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(291, 53)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 20))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 20))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0422\u0443\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u0435\u043d \u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
    # retranslateUi





class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(u"listWidget")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)





class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    # retranslateUi

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(200, 40)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        for i in range(20):
            testwidget = TestWidget()
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
            testwidget.setText(f"Это элемент {i}")
            testwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.test(i))
            item.setSizeHint(testwidget.sizeHint())
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, testwidget)

    def test(self, i):
        print("Элемент", i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас две шибки, которые вы допустили. Спросите если что-то не понятно.

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(291, 53)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 20))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 20))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"\u0422\u0443\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u0435\u043d \u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
    # retranslateUi


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(u"listWidget")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


#class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
#                          vvvvvvv
class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):                                           # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    # retranslateUi

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(200, 40)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        for i in range(20):
            testwidget = TestWidget()
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
            testwidget.setText(f"Это элемент {i}")
# +++                        
#            testwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.test(i))                                      
            testwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.test(i))          # +++
            
            item.setSizeHint(testwidget.sizeHint())
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, testwidget)

    def test(self, i):
        print("Элемент", i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот код действительно работает на PyQt5, но к сожалению при попытке его использования на Pyside6 я получаю ошибку 'TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ch''

Comment: @MRX попробуйте заменить `testwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.test(i))` на `testwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.test(ch, i))` и `def test(self, i):` на `def test(self, ch, i):`

Comment: testwidget.pushButton.clicked[bool].connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.test(i))  # +++
Я нашел решение на сторонних источниках, нужно было добавить [bool] после clicked, теперь всё работает, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @MRX пожалуйста.